# Find the prime factorization of $x^3-x+1$ in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ and in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Find the prime factorization of $x^3-x+1$ in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ and in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$.

The polynomial $x^3-x+1$ no roots in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ and is of degree $3$ so I think it implies that it's irreducible and has no factorization?

Similarly it has not roots in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$ so it's irreducible. Have I understood something wrong or is the question just poorly worded?

Comment: Check your work for $\mathbb Z_5[x]$. (I presume $\mathbb Z_5$ means $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$).

Comment: Does $\mathbb{Z}_p$ refer to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (a finite field for primes $p$) or to [the $p$-adic integers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#p-adic_integers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $x^3-x+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$ but not in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$. Notice that
$$(-2)^3-(-2)+1=-8+2+1=-5\equiv 0 \pmod{5}.$$
After the division by $(x+2)$, we find that its factorization in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$ is
$$x^3-x+1=(x+2)(x^2+3x+3).$$
It is easy to verify that $x^2+3x+3$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_5[x]$.